# Updating Progress Bar displayed in Popup in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

How do you update a progress bar that is displayed in Kivy. In the following example I get `AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'`. The issue is in the following line

```
self.ids.progress.value = value
```

I can see why since the `progressBar` widget is in `<LoadingPopup>` and not `<MainScreen>` but after trying several different things I can't reference the `progressBar` widget in `<LoadingPopup>` from the `do_update method`.

Thanks in advance

```
import threading
from functools import partial

from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.spinner import Spinner
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup



Builder.load_string('''

<LoadingPopup>:
    title: "Popup"
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 400, 400
    auto_dismiss: False

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        ProgressBar:
            id: progress
            size_hint: (1.0, 0.06)

<MainScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        Spinner:
            id: first
            text: ' First Number'
            values: ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']

        Spinner:
            id: second
            text: ' Second Number'
            values: ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']

        Label:
            id: result
            text: ' Result'
            color: 0,0,0,1
        Button:
            id: res
            on_press: root.doit_in_thread(first.text,second.text)
            text: 'Multiply'


''')

class LoadingPopup(Popup):

    def __init__(self, obj, **kwargs):
        super(LoadingPopup, self).__init__(**kwargs)


class MainScreen(FloatLayout):
    changet = StringProperty()
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def doit_in_thread(self, fir, sec):
        popup = LoadingPopup(self)
        popup.open()
        threading.Thread(target=partial(self.onMul, fir, sec, popup)).start()

    def do_update(self, value, text, *args):
        self.ids.progress.value = value
        self.ids.result.text = text

    def onMul(self,fir,sec, popup):
        a = (int(fir)*int(sec))
        print(a)
        b = 0
        old_value = 0
        endRange = 1000000
        for i in range(endRange):
            progress = int(((i+1)*100)/endRange)
            if progress != old_value and progress % 5 == 0:
                text = str(b*(int(fir)*int(sec)))
                Clock.schedule_once(partial(self.do_update, progress, text))
                old_value = progress
            b+=1

        popup.dismiss()

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainScreen()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it, is to keep a reference of the popup so you can address it later:

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(MainScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.popup = LoadingPopup(self)

def doit_in_thread(self, fir, sec):
    self.popup.open()
    threading.Thread(target=partial(self.onMul, fir, sec, self.popup)).start()

def do_update(self, value, text, *args):
    self.popup.ids.progress.value = value
    self.ids.result.text = text
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python Code

1. Replace all references of `popup` with `self.popup` so that you can access it in the methods inside class MainScreen.
2. Replace `self.ids.progress.value` with `self.popup.ids.progress.value`
3. Since `a = (int(fir)*int(sec)`, replace `str(b*(int(fir)*int(sec)))` with `str(b * a)`
4. Don't need to pass `popup` to `onMul` method, access it using `self.popup`

### Snippet

```
class MainScreen(FloatLayout):
    changet = StringProperty()

    def doit_in_thread(self, fir, sec):
        self.popup = LoadingPopup(self)
        self.popup.open()
        threading.Thread(target=partial(self.onMul, fir, sec)).start()

    def do_update(self, value, text, *args):
        self.popup.ids.progress.value = value
        self.ids.result.text = text

    def onMul(self, fir, sec):
        a = (int(fir)*int(sec))
        print(a)
        b = 0
        old_value = 0
        endRange = 1000000
        for i in range(endRange):
            progress = int(((i+1)*100)/endRange)
            if progress != old_value and progress % 5 == 0:
                text = str(b*(int(fir)*int(sec)))
                # text = str(b * a)
                print("\ttext=", text)
                Clock.schedule_once(partial(self.do_update, progress, text))
                old_value = progress
            b+=1
    self.popup.dismiss()
```

## kv file

The `result` is not visible because the default background colour of Label widget is black, and the text colour for `result` is also set to black, `color: 0,0,0,1`. Therefore, remove `color: 0,0,0,1`.

### Snippet

```
    Label:
        id: result
        text: ' Result'
```

## Output

[image: Img01]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If my answer solved your problem, feel free to up-vote and/or accept it, as you see fit. Than you.